# Nome específico para as rochas atrás de uma cachoeira

Tags: vocabulário

Há uma palavra específica para as rochas atrás de uma cachoeira?

A única palavra que me ocorre é *encosta*, mas estou curioso para saber se há algo mais específico.

Exemplo do que estou a dizer:

[image: rochas atrás da cachoeira]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, não há uma palavra específica e, no seu caso, são rochas mesmo. Outros vocábulos como álveo, encosta, vertente, rochas ou leito, são inespecíficos e podem significar o leito de um curso dágua **ou** apenas um terreno inclinado. Mas não as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Sou do Nordeste do Brasil, e nunca me preocupei em usar uma palavra específica para isso, se é que existe. Talvez alguém na área de geografia use um termo assim. *Eu apenas as descrevo do jeito que prefiro.*

Exemplos são: *Pedras*; *Rochas*; *Rochedos*.

Acredito que, dentre essas, a palavra mais específica seja *Rochedo*, que significa:

- *Agregado ou conjunto de rochas — Várias rochas*;
- *Rocha gigante — Rocha isolada, pontiaguda e de grande elevação*;
- *Rocha escarpada à beira-mar*;
- *Rochas nas proximidades do mar — por extensão, cachoeiras, rios, etc*;
- *Penedo*.

Aí, é só escolher qual quer usar. Tanto faz.

Exemplo: *As rochas dessa cachoeira são bonitas, né?*

Caso pegue do inglês *slope*, pode-se usar *vertente*, *declive (ladeira abaixo)*, *aclive (ladeira cima)*, por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado.